# How does the internal resistance of a cell vary with temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, electrical-resistance, batteries

Does anyone have a physics explanation to why the internal resistance of a battery decreases as the temperature increases?

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* king jigg!  The community does expect that questions *show* some effort to research and think through the problem.  Your question as written does not show any such effort.  I recommend that you edit your question to show that you've done some research and thought about the problem enough to list at least one plausible reason for the variation of internal resistance with temperature.  For example, that the chemical reactions within the cell are temperature dependent.

Answer (score 1):

in a (cheap) battery, charges get transported between the electrodes by ion movements in liquids or paste-like substances. the warmer these substances get, the easier it is for the ions to diffuse through them under the influence of a charge imbalance, and the internal resistance of the battery goes down.

Comment: So it might be related to viscosity isn't it?

Comment: it might (that is a testable hypothesis) but remember that  the electrochemical equations themselves also contain exp(kT) terms- that is, their rates are strong functions of temperature.

Answer (score -2):

Isn't it just that the resistance of any galvanic cell such as a battery decreases as temperature increases due to increased electron mobility at higher temps.

Easy?

Comment: You should probably just post an objective answer. Just because you think something is easy doesn't mean others do.

Comment: No, the electron do not conduct the current there. In the electrolyte, the currents are ion currents. It is chemistry, not so easy.